# R markdown fails when deployed in Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny, shiny-server

I have application which is deployed in shinyapps.io One the features of the app is generate reports of the analysis result in pdf format.

All other functions of the app works fine except for generation of the report.
When clicked on "Download Report" in the app it grays out saying **Disconnected from the server**.  The reports are generated as required when its run through local IDE and opened from external browser.

`Reports.Rmd`

````
---
title: " Analysis Report"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: \usepackage{fancyhdr}

---
  \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{1.png}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 


##Engine Details

Selected Class Type: `r input$c_type`  
Selected Room :`r input$rm_num`  


##Analysis Result

Percentage of data points spread: `r (nrow(subtable())/nrow(nonzero()))* 
 100`  
Average Marks: `r mean(subtable()$Marks)`  


##Trend Analysis Graph for the selected data 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(gridExtra)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
          PredictedCN = feforplot()
          Subt = subtable()$Sbt
          plot(Subt,type = "o",lwd=2,col = "red", xlab = "A", ylab = "B",
             main = "A v/s B",xlim=c(100,1500),ylim=c(0,10))

          lines (PredictedCN, type = "o", col = "blue")

          VS = subtable()$V.S
          plot(VS,type = "o",col = "red", xlab = "VS", ylab = "Analysis",
             main = "Analytical R",xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,10))


```

##Input File  Details

Input file name: `r filename()`  
Input file size in bytes: `r filesize()`   
Total number of rows: `r nrow(dataframe())`    
Total number of columns: `r ncol(dataframe())`  
Report generated date: `r date()`
````

`Server.R`**This is code snippet for download handler in Server script**

```
output$reportpdf <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste('my-report', sep = '.', 'pdf')
},


content = function(file) {
  src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

  # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
  # permission to the current working directory
  owd <- setwd(tempdir())
  on.exit(setwd(owd))
  file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

  library(rmarkdown)
  out <- render('report.Rmd', pdf_document())
  file.rename(out, file)

}
 )
```

`Shiny App.io Logs`

```
processing file: reports.Rmd
inline  R code fragments
|      | 0%|20%|40%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options)
List of 1
$echo: logi FALSE
```

Comment: Is it possible that pandoc is not installed on the server?